# For video games terminology, what is the proper translation for "range"

Tags: translation, vocabulary, word-requests

I'm playing around with my mother tongue so I tried to translate sentences that I might write into Chinese. One of them was this sentence, in English.

"The great strength of Annie comes from the long range of her fire ball."

I put in:

安妮的主力是她的很长的(???)火球.

What should be in the missing slot?

Comment: "Great strength" should not be translated to "主力". Simply "强大的力量" fits more. I would translate the whole sentence like "安妮强大的力量来自于她远射程的火球".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In gaming field, `(of) long range` is commonly translated into `远程` or `远距离`, and `ranged attacked` is `远程攻击`. You can use `射程` when you want to express the notion of `range`.

By the way, `主力` is not the right word for `strength`. If you use `主力` here, it means `primary (attack method)`. To say `strength` you may want to use `强项` or `优势`.

So I would translate this way:

> "The great strength of Annie comes from the long range of her fire ball."
>
> 安妮最大的优势是她远距离的火球。

Answer (score 1):

I would use 射程, which means "range of fire" in English. Are you sure that you have all those 的s in the right place?  Although 远程 is the more common way of expressing long range, it obviously cannot be inserted into the sentence given.

Comment: It sounds right as a naive Chinese speaker, but I don't know if it is necessarily grammatical.

Comment: how does 她长程的火球 sound to you?

Comment: That sounds fine, though a little clipped. Adding the 'de' clarifying after 她 feels a little more fluid than me, but it would be understandable.

Comment: I would use 她射程很长的火球, or 她的火球的射程很长

Comment: we all seem to agree that ... 的火球 is the way to go

Comment: 射程 is perfectly right in this case. But 射程 is not suitable for melee attackers imho. 攻击范围/距离 is more general.

Answer (score 1):

Long range ballistic missiles are translated as 远程导弹

so I would say 远程火球